# How do i speed up this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, performance

Here the situation, 
Im trying to generate a report from my Oracle DB which consists of a lot of rows, i have about 5 minutes query time right now and wanted to see if theres any way to alter the query that might speed up the querytime,

```
SELECT ib1.id as InvoiceNumber,
ib1.shipmentno as ShipmentNumber,
ib1.ref as ConsignorRef, 
cons1.name as ConsName,
ib1.consolidation_type as ShipmentType, 
to_char(ib1.custom_field12, 'YYYYMMDDhhmmss') as InvoiceDate, 
ib1.reg_time as HousingDate, 
ib1.list_add_time as Pickup, 
ib1.confirm_date as Date, 
ex1.stat_date as Timestamp, 
ib1.date_prefered as ETA, 
ib1.field7 as Housing, 
ib1.countrycode as Country
FROM Invoice ib1,
     ek_export ex1,
      ek_cons cons1
WHERE ib1.ex_id=124
AND ib1.id=ex1.ib_id
AND ex1.state_type='DELIVERED'
AND ib1.cons_id=cons1.id
AND ex1.ex_id=124
AND trunc(ib1.reg_time) BETWEEN to_date('2009-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND to_date('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY ib1.id
```

Any tips?

Comment: Try replacing `trunc(ib1.reg_time)` with just `ib1.reg_time`.

Comment: (Just to clarify, if you adjust your limits to use `< next day`, the `TRUNC` is not needed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check that your query uses indexes.

I think you'll have to index :

- ex1.ib_id
- ex1.state_type
- ib1.cons_id
- ex1.ex_id
- ib1.reg_time

Additionaly, avoid use of functions in query condition, try to directly put result of function

- to_date('2009-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') replaced by the result if possible
- trunc(ib1.reg_time), try to store already "trunc"ed value

Then, make your join like said in Ingo's answer to have better control on your joins.

Finally, you order your results by ib1.id, is it necessary ? if not, remove the order clause.

Check at this documentation of Oracle, it's about analysis of query.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: Using a function on a constant value or parameter, like `to_date()`, is not a problem. Using a function on a column, like `trunc()`, is serious problem.

Comment: ok for to_date(), but i think it's a little possible optimization.

Comment: You can replace that condition with `AND (ib1.reg_time >= DATE'2009-01-01' AND ib1.reg_time < DATE'2010-01-01')` which might use an index and will not call the `trunc()` function a trillion times.

Answer (score 2):

You need to analyze the query. You may look at the execution plan and also review the index created on each of the participating tables.

The rule of the thumb is that there should be index created on the columns that participate in the where clause and order by clause.

Another similar question is here: [Making my SQL Query more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599898/making-my-sql-query-more-efficient)

Comment: question is about oracle

Comment: @djleop: I am aware that it is for Oracle. However, basic concepts are same for any RDBMS.

Comment: Here is a documentation about how to analyze query in oracle : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Answer (score 0):

there is 2 step of a query, the query itself and the fetching, i think that the fetching can't be compressed. Can you say the time of each steps. (mysql-worbench give both informations)

Comment: `mysql-workbench` doesn't work as well with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

your query first takes a cross join over all tables and then filters the huge result in your where clause... use inner joins to select only the rows that matter in the first place ... like

```
...
from invoice ib1 
join ek_export ex1 on ib1.id = ex1.ib_id
join ek_cons cons1 on ib1.cons_id = cons1.id
...
```

Comment: This is just plainly wrong. While it's good for other reasons to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax, it matters zero in regards of efficiency.

Comment: Agreed with ypercube here.  If you have a *really bad* planner I supposed it might make a difference, but with any half-decent planner, explicit vs cross join and filter will be treated as equivalent.  As this is Oracle, we can rule that out.

Comment: agreed to both your comments. basically the rdbms' optimizers usually optimize both kinds of queries to the same execution plan... in theory if they didnt optimize tho it would make a difference, but as you pointed out any major rdbms should nowadays properly take care of this issue